# How to convert byte[] type to Certificate type in java?

Tags: java, certificate, arrays

I've a `byte[]` of certificate data and I want to change this `byte[]` type to `Certificate` type. How can I achieve this?

Now I used `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(InputStream inStream)`.

```
byte[] csr = getCSR(cn, ou, org, loc, state, country,email);
CertificateFactory  cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(csr);
Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bais);
```

But Error occurred **Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bais);** at this line.

Error : **java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)**

Why this error occurred? What wrong in this code? Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(InputStream inStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29) to generate a Certificate.

Here is an example which generates an X509 Certificate:

```
CertificateFactory cf   = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
```

Comment: Now, I used just like this `CertificateFactory  cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");Certificate certificate = 
      cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));` but I've an error **java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)**. Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: @shariphwar giving the type of exception instead of where it happens (or both) would help...

Comment: Error : **java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)**

Comment: I edit my question please check my question and answer me. Thanks.

Comment: What if the certificate contains password? Does it not prevent it from reading it?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error when I try to use CertificateFactory.generateCertificate on CSR.
So I think your problem could be the same; i.e. your byte array does not contain certificate, but certificate signing request.
If you really need to read certificate signing request (as I do), use the following code (inspired by http://www.journaldev.com/223/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-using-java-api):

```
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10;
...
PKCS10 csr = new PKCS10(Base64Utils.decode(csrPem1.getBytes()));
```

Using Base64Utils depends on the format of input data.