# Persisting an X509 Certificate to MySQL database, using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a dynamic web service using the Java Cryptography API, and MySQL.

The project I am working on requires that RSA certificates can be saved to database, or shared with other users over the internet.

Specifically, does anyone know the best method for persisting an X509Certificate object to a MySQL database?

Thank you.

Comment: Save it as a `byte[]` in a `BLOB`.

Comment: Can I use this method?: public abstract byte[] getEncoded()

Comment: Yup, you can then use the `Blob.getBinaryStream()` method to [get a certificate back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424817/how-to-convert-byte-type-to-certificate-type-in-java).